# how can i redirect user , seller and admin to their panel in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

i have  level column in user table , i wanna redirect to their panel in laravel after login but i dont know where check and redirect user???
i try to login safty

Can this code be correct?

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
     if(auth()->user()->isAdmin())
    {
        return redirect('/admin/panel');
    } elseif(auth()->user()->isWriter())
    {
        return redirect('/writer/panel');
    }
    return redirect('/user/panel');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite `redirectPath()` method to your `LoginController`.

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (auth()->user()->isAdmin())
        {
            return '/admin/panel';
        }
        elseif (auth()->user()->isWriter())
        {
            return '/writer/panel';
        }
        return '/user/panel';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In LoginController that uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait for authentication you must override the **redirectTo()** method and write your own logic. so you must something like this code:

```
 protected function redirectTo(){
        $user = User::whereId(Auth::id())->first();

        if(isset($user)){
            if($user->role == 'admin'){
                return '/admin/panel';    //path to admin panel
            }elseif($user->role == 'writer'){
                return '/writer/panle';   //path to writer panel
            }
        }
        return '/';
    }
```